# Spring SAML Sample application returns Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have been trying to get the Spring SAML Sample application up and running, but have been struggling for days, and searching the internet with no success. I have followed all the steps in the Quick start guide.... when I click the 'Start single sign-on' button, I get redirected to SSOCircle, I log in, and get redirected back to the sample application, but it returns the following error:

```
Message:
Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial 

StackTrace:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The stack trace from Tomcat is as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1220)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.tryJKS(KeyStoreBuilder.java:450)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:83)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1220)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.tryJKS(KeyStoreBuilder.java:450)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:416)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:83)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:436)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:83)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
    at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
    at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any help would be much apprectiated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most likely hitting a bug in the underlying OpenSAML and SSL library which presumes that file `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` or `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/jssecacerts` is present and can be read as a JKS or PKCS12 keystore. In your case the file is probably corrupted.

Please try updating the cacerts file in your JDK with the file from the original installation. Make sure you can read it using `keytool -list -keystore cacerts` with either an empty password or password "*changeit*".

Comment: I can list certificates in the cacerts file using keytool, and have also added the certificate to cacerts, although the sample application uses its own keystore, which I also checked with keytool, and I can also list the certificates in that file. The strange thing is when I view the metadata it is managing to read the certificate because it returns the public key as part of the metadata - not sure why it wouldn't be able to read the certificate when the data is returned from SSOCircle?

Comment: I'd suggest you get sources for the library from http://central.maven.org/maven2/ca/juliusdavies/not-yet-commons-ssl/0.3.9/, put a breakpoint to class KeyStoreBuilder, line 266 and debug the logic which will reveal the error. My wild guess is that your JAVA_HOME property points to a wrong place.

Comment: I couldn't find the sources for KeyStoreBuilder? I did manage to get a bit more information by setting the logging to 'debug'... it appears to be failing while trying to extract the certificate from the returned SAML message (the last log message before the exception is: Attempting to extract credential from an X509Data)

Comment: I did check JAVA_HOME, and it is pointing to the correct location... one other thing to note is I am developing on OSX with JDK 1.7, I tried running the application on an Ubuntu Linux box with the OpenJDK 1.7 and I got the same error

Comment: Please do try the debug, the sources for the file are in the link I already sent you above - http://central.maven.org/maven2/ca/juliusdavies/not-yet-commons-ssl/0.3.9/, file not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9-sources.jar

Comment: It most likely fails during initialization of static blocks in class TrustMaterial (lines 73-112), check at line 99 whether both cacerts and jssecacerts are null? The code will get invoked once you receive response back from IDP.

Comment: I managed to debug the TrustMaterial class. It loads the cacerts file, but when it calls `KeyStoreBuilder.parse(jsk, password)` (line 207), the password is null. This causes KeystoreBuilder to fall over on line 455: `jksKeystore.getKey(alias, password)` - this is while it's trying to load the certificate I added. This calls onto the sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore class which has `throw new UnrecoverableKeyException("Password must not be null")` on line 50. I'm not sure how to get around this because the TrustMaterial class always gets created with a null password?

Comment: I figured out the problem... I had added my certificate to cacerts with the private key instead of just adding the public key.

Comment: Super Nikolai, I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: This has blocked me for long time. After _many_ tries, the last thing that solved the problem has been to remove from cacerts (be careful and check the one that is loaded in tomcat startup) every key pair and certificate added, even if keytool din't show any problem listing keystore.

Comment: @marcobonfigli We also had added our Tomcat key pair (for SSL connection) to the cacerts and because of that `java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.` exception occurred. Apparently key pairs should not be in the cacerts keystore. We removed the key pair from the cacerts keystore (to a new keystore) and our SAML application started without errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Same issue, upgraded to not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.16.jar from the bundled 3.9 of saml-sample and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a mac with Java 1.6 - here's what I found:

TrustMaterial.java is running static init code ->

```
    String pathToCacerts = javaHome + "/lib/security/cacerts";
    String pathToJSSECacerts = javaHome + "/lib/security/jssecacerts";
    TrustMaterial cacerts = null;
    TrustMaterial jssecacerts = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(pathToCacerts);
        if (f.exists()) {
            cacerts = new TrustMaterial(pathToCacerts);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        File f = new File(pathToJSSECacerts);
        if (f.exists()) {
            jssecacerts = new TrustMaterial(pathToJSSECacerts);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CACERTS = cacerts;
    JSSE_CACERTS = jssecacerts;
    if (JSSE_CACERTS != null) {
        DEFAULT = JSSE_CACERTS;
    } else {
        DEFAULT = CACERTS;
    }
```

Now, above there is a bug mentioned about assuming `JAVA_HOME/lib/security/...` files are valid keystores.  If *neither of these files are valid keystores both CACERTS and JSSE_CACERTS are null* and this line at line 127 causes the NPE because `JSSE_CACERTS` is null:

```
this.jks = CACERTS != null ? CACERTS.jks : JSSE_CACERTS.jks;
```

So, why are both null?

When I look at mine on my filesystem:

```
file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

I get this:

> > /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts: broken symbolic link to /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts

That's a symlink to an invalid cacerts keystore.  What I did was get a good copy of a JDK1.6 keystore via this command:

`sudo find / -name 'cacerts' 2>/dev/null`

> > /some/other/path/to/cacerts

Then, do `file /some/other/path/to/cacerts` to make sure you get a valid file:

> > /some/other/path/to/cacerts: Java KeyStore

Copy that to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts` to replace your broken symlink and verify it's good:

`file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts`

> > /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts: Java KeyStore

Once that's a valid keystore, this code will work.

What a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

I got this or very similar problem with openjdk11, turns out to be this bug:

https://github.com/narupley/not-going-to-be-commons-ssl/issues/5

defaultKeystoreType was pkcs12 (seems to be in newer java version) and there seems to be a bug in not-going-to-be-commons 0.3.19 that causes this problem since pkcs12 as opposed to jks requires a password to see the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

check jre Installed Extensions https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html

In my case the problem was that I had had **another bcprov jar inside** the external jre library path "**/jre/lib/ext**" that was caused a conflict with the bcprov in the maven pom file,** after removing** from "/jre/lib/ext" the **problem **was **fixed**